# app script web app can't access google docs if anonymous

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-authentication

Goal: create an apps script web app that opens a google doc and returns it's name

This functionality stopped working sometime in the last month or so.

- create apps script project
- add a doGet

> ```
> function doGet(e) {
>     var msg = "none;";
>     try{
>       var doc = DocumentApp.openById("1WYNw9IPcsYZXrvK7gOaoOLt7GPiaUhCJ5OEf79h~~~~"); 
>       msg = doc.getName();
>     }catch(e){
>       msg = e;
>     }  
>     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg);  
> }
> ```

Save and follow path for authentication

Publish / Deploy as web app with settings

- new version because anon unable to use dev version of url
- execute as me
- Anyone, even anonymous

Now try it out

- open the url in authenticated browser

  - not the test url
  - success

> Found and opened Intro

open the url in incognito and do not login to any account

Error message

> Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and
> try again.

Edit : added the line msg = doc.getName();

Comment: It does not show any error. Can you provide more information?

Comment: added msg = doc.getName();  then still no error???

Answer (score 2):

This works for me even including a new incognito window and another account.

```
function doGet(e) {
    var msg = "none;";
    try{
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById("docid"); 
      msg = doc.getName();
    }catch(e){
      msg = e;
    }  
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that edit @Cooper I forgot to remove that.

Comment: Thanks for trying that after fixing the missing line msg= doc.getName(); your subject says "and another account". You did try incognito and NO account, right?

Comment: I did try it and yes, it does work on incognito and NO account logged.